# Bash - Store Color Codes in Variable

Tags: bash, colors, variable

How do I store colored text in a variable and print it with color later?

I never see the answer to this question in 100 searches it's all about PS1 prompts, or inline printf's or using data from ls --color.  I need to add the color to the variable myself AND have it print colorized later.

```
name="Hello"
name=$name"\e[36m\(Test\)\e[0m"
echo $name
printf $name
```

the ouptut i get from this is:

```
Hello \e[36m(Test)\e0m
```

It doesn't colorize from the data in the variable.
how do we STORE the color code in a variable for printing later 
Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Comment: `\e` is a special escape code specifically for `echo -e` which is parsed into an Escape character,`^[` (literally, Ctrl-[; not caret [).  To store that into a variable without learning type a literal Escape in your editor, you can use (for example), `BOLD="$(echo -e "\e[1m")"` followed by `echo $BOLD`.

Comment: Bash's echo will not interpret `\e` unless called as `echo -e`, but printf should. Does neither of your calls result in color printing?

Comment: Nowadays I save the escape codes as snippets in my text editor instead of using variables. the reason is I always end up wanting to use the escape codes in scripts where the variables weren't initialised - so if you just put the raw escape code into the script - you dont need the variables to be available - but you do lose the human readable variable name

Comment: Yes.  In the direct code above, when I run that script i get the same output regardless of echo or printf. In the long run for what I was trying to do, I solved it a different way, but the answers on this thread are rather educational.

Answer (score 4):

In bash there are three options: `echo -e`, `printf`, and `$'...'`.

The last one is the easiest:

```
$ name="Hello"; name=$name$'\033[34m(Test)\e[0m' ; echo "$name"
Hello(Test)
```

In this case the color code was stored in the variable. The easiest way to "see" the codes (apart from seeing the color) is to use some hex viewer:

```
$ echo "$name" | od -vAn -tcx1
   H   e   l   l   o 033   [   3   5   m   (   T   e   s   t   )
  48  65  6c  6c  6f  1b  5b  33  35  6d  28  54  65  73  74  29
 033   [   0   m  \n
  1b  5b  30  6d  0a
```

Use it when you need to "see" the codes (and why they do or don't work).

The color codes are inside the var, already interpreted. In that way you could create a var for some color, and use it:

```
$ blue=$'\033[34m'; reset=$'\033[0m'
$ echo "Hello $blue Test $reset Colors"
```

The other way is to store the codes inside a variable, and interpret them each time their "effect" is needed.

```
$ blue='\033[34m'; reset='\033[0m'
$ echo "Hello $blue Test $reset Colors"
Hello \033[34m Test \033[0m Colors
$ echo -e "Hello $blue Test $reset Colors"
Hello  Test  Colors
```

With "Test" in Blue, and "Colors" in Black (if your console screen is white).

The command `echo -e` is not as portable (and safe) as printf:

```
$ blue='\033[34m'; reset='\033[0m'
$ printf "%s $blue%s $reset%s" "Hello" "Test" "Colors"
Hello Test Colors
```

The whole list of colors (background) will be visible with (printing an space):

```
 printf '\e[%sm ' {40..47} 0; echo
```

Or, with foreground colors:

```
 printf '\e[%smColor=%s  ' {30..37}{,} 0 0; echo
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than

```
name="Hello"
name=$name"\e[36m\(Test\)\e[0m"
echo $name
printf $name
```

you could make it a little simpler to follow with

```
name="Hello"
name=$name"$(tput setaf 6)(Test)$(tput sgr0)"
echo $name
printf $name
```

That approach would make it simpler than remembering the appropriate strings for extended colors (beyond 8).  For instance, running this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# = 0 ] && exec $0 6
name="Hello"
name=$name"$(tput setaf $1)(Test)$(tput sgr0)"
echo $name
printf $name
```

with parameter 6, 12, 24 and `TERM` set to [`xterm-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-xterm-256color), the corresponding `$name` with `\E` as escape would be

```
Hello\E[36m(Test)\E(B\E[m
Hello\E[94m(Test)\E(B\E[m
Hello\E[38;5;24m(Test)\E(B\E[m
```

For reference:

- [tput(1)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)
- POSIX [echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) and [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (no `\e` in either)
- OSX [echo(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/echo.1.html) and [printf(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/printf.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/printf) (same comment)
- Linux [echo(1)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) and [printf(1)](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) (provides `\e`)
- Bash [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) (its *builtin* `echo` can differ from `/bin/echo`, same for `printf`)

Answer (score 1):

`\e` is a special escape code specifically for `echo -e` which is parsed into an Escape character,`^[` (literally, Ctrl-[; not caret [).  To store that into a variable without learning type a literal Escape in your editor, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
BOLD="$( echo -e "\e[1m" )"
CYAN="$( echo -e "\e[36m" )"

echo "I am feeling ${BOLD}really ${CYAN}blue!"
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` should display the colors correctly

```
[user@host ~]$ name="Hello"
[user@host ~]$ name=$name"\e[36m\(Test\)\e[0m"
[user@host ~]$ echo $name
Hello\e[36m\(Test\)\e[0m
[user@host ~]$ printf $name
Hello\(Test\)[user@host ~]$
```

In the last line "Test" is cyan and there is no new line.

---

for `echo` you need to add `-e`:

```
$ help echo
[...]
Options:
      -n        do not append a newline
      -e        enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
      -E        explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes
[...]
```

You can store colors in variables as long as you use `echo -e`.

```
export txtblk='\033[0;30m' # Black - Regular
export txtred='\033[0;31m' # Red
export txtgrn='\033[0;32m' # Green
export txtylw='\033[0;33m' # Yellow
export txtblu='\033[0;34m' # Blue
export txtpur='\033[0;35m' # Purple
export txtcyn='\033[0;36m' # Cyan
export txtwht='\033[0;37m' # White
export bldblk='\033[1;30m' # Black - Bold
export bldred='\033[1;31m' # Red
export bldgrn='\033[1;32m' # Green
[...]
export undblk='\033[4;30m' # Black - Underline
export undred='\033[4;31m' # Red
[...]
export bakblk='\033[40m'   # Black - Background
export bakred='\033[41m'   # Red
export badgrn='\033[42m'   # Green
export txtrst='\033[0m'    # Text Reset

[user@host ~]$ echo "$txtblu hello"
\033[0;34m hello
[user@host ~]$ echo -e "$txtblu hello"
hello # this text is blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANSI C quoting to have the special characters translated: `$'...'`. So that is a dollar before the single quotes. This allows one to type `\n` and `\t` for newline and tab, but also for color codes.

```
name="Hello"
name=$name$'\e[36m\(Test\)\e[0m'
echo $name
printf $name
```

These ANSI C escapes were introduced KSH more recent than the 88 version, and are available on `bash`, `zsh` and `busybox sh`. It is not available on `dash`.